# Permesso di Soggiorno Illimitato

Tags: italy, permesso-di-soggiorno

I am planning to visit my sick relative in Italy. I  have a *permesso di soggiorno illimitato*. I went to the UK using my family visa that time and I was not able to return right away to Italy because of COVID restrictions. I would like to ask if I can still travel using my *permesso di soggiorno illimitato*, to Italy just for 10 days? I also have my *carta d'identita* valid until 2030.  I appreciate any answer. Cheers.

Comment: If you have an "unlimited permit to stay" and valid Italian ID, why are you concerned that you would not be allowed to enter/stay in Italy?

Comment: @lambshaanxy Many countries assume that if you no longer **reside** in a country, you don't need a **residence permit**. This is often 6 months for a normal residence permit and for a permanent one 12 (or longer) months.

Answer (score -1):

> I went to the UK using my family visa that time and I was not able to return right away to Italy because of COVID restrictions.

Due to the lack of details (did you deregister you residence in Italy? ; Has you official residence in the United Kingdom been longer than 12 months?) no pricise answer can be given.

From what you have written ('I am planning to **visit** my sick relative in Italy'), you yourself don't consider yourself a resident of Italy.

It would be better to apply for a visa if you require one (if you don't: you can enter as a visitor) to avoid a entry refusal if it is noticed that the residence permit has be revolked.

---

It would seem that the former Permesso di Soggiorno **with** the qualifier **Illimitato** (*Indefinite*) is now called **Permesso di Soggiorno UE per Soggiornanti di Lungo Periodo** (*EU residence permit for long-term residents*):

| Permesso di Soggiorno (2007 and 2021) |
| --- |
| [image] |
| [image] |

The conditions for this residence permit are set out in Article 9 of (the updated) LEGISLATIVE DECREE 25 July 1998, n. 286.

Paragraph 7 states that such a residence permit is revoked after a consecutive absence from the territory of the European Union of 12 months.

- for those who held a Blue Card: 24 months (Art. 9-ter Paragraph 4)

---

> **DECRETO LEGISLATIVO 25 luglio 1998 , n. 286**
> **Art. 9**
> **Permesso di soggiorno UE per soggiornanti di lungo periodo**
> **1.** Lo straniero in possesso, da almeno cinque anni, di un permesso di soggiorno in corso di validità, che dimostra la disponibilità di un reddito non inferiore all'importo annuo dell'assegno sociale e, nel caso di richiesta relativa ai familiari, di un reddito sufficiente secondo i parametri indicati nell'articolo 29, comma 3, lettera b) e di un alloggio idoneo che rientri nei parametri minimi previsti dalla legge regionale per gli alloggi di edilizia residenziale pubblica ovvero che sia fornito dei requisiti di idoneità igienico-sanitaria accertati dall'Azienda unità sanitaria locale competente per territorio, puo' chiedere al questore il rilascio del permesso di soggiorno UE per soggiornanti di lungo periodo, per sé e per i familiari di cui all'articolo 29, comma 1. (24) (29)
> ...
> **7.** Il permesso di soggiorno di cui al comma 1 **è revocato**:
> a) se è stato acquisito fraudolentemente;
> b) in caso di espulsione, di cui al comma 10;
> c) quando mancano o vengano a mancare le condizioni per il rilascio, di cui al comma 4;
> d) **in caso di assenza dal territorio dell'Unione per un periodo di dodici mesi consecutivi**;
> e) in caso di conferimento di permesso di soggiorno di lungo periodo da parte di altro Stato membro dell'Unione europea, previa comunicazione da parte di quest'ultimo, e comunque in caso di assenza dal territorio dello Stato per un periodo superiore a sei anni.
>
> > **LEGISLATIVE DECREE 25 July 1998, n. 286**
> > **Article 9**
> > **EU residence permit for long-term residents**
> > **1.** The foreigner who has been in possession, for at least five years, of a valid residence permit, which demonstrates the availability of an income not less than the annual amount of the social allowance and, in the case of a request relating to family members, of a sufficient income according to the parameters indicated in article 29, paragraph 3, letter b) and suitable accommodation that falls within the minimum parameters established by the regional law for public residential housing or that meets the hygienic-sanitary suitability requirements ascertained by the local health unit competent for the territory, he can ask the police commissioner to issue the EU residence permit for long-term residents, for himself and his family members referred to in article 29, paragraph 1. (24) (29)
> > ...
> > **7.** The residence permit referred to in paragraph 1 **is revoked**:
> > a) if it was acquired fraudulently;
> > b) in case of expulsion, referred to in paragraph 10;
> > c) when the conditions for release referred to in paragraph 4 are missing or no longer exist;
> > d) **in case of absence from the territory of the Union for a period of twelve consecutive months**;
> > e) in case of granting of a long-term residence permit by another Member State of the European Union, upon communication from the latter, and in any case in case of absence from the territory of the State for a period exceeding six years.

---

**Sources**:

- [LEGISLATIVE DECREE 25 July 1998, n. 286](https://www.normattiva.it/esporta/attoCompleto?atto.dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=1998-08-18&atto.codiceRedazionale=098G0348) (Italian only)

  - Consolidated text of the provisions concerning the regulation of immigration and rules on the condition of foreigners.

Comment: All that assumes her residency.has been revoked, but how would they even know she was outside the EU for 12 months? There's no central Schengen database for this.  Plus during COVID many rules were bent because people like the OP could not travel at all.

Comment: @lambshaanxy In such cases the burden proof lies with the OP. If they, or the spouse, has deregistered (or the spouse is Italian and registered in the AIRE system) that would be enough to start an investigation. And travel restrictions caused by COVID are long over.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I’m hazy on Schengen passport-stamping protocol, but if the OP is a non-EU national wouldn’t their passport be stamped on exiting Italy/the EU? Meaning the UK entry stamp and lack of a return stamp for Italy/EU would reveal the OP’s 12 months+ absence?

Comment: @Traveller This is something that would only be investigated when applying for Italian citizenship. Otherwise people can spend decades on a permanent residency without anyone ever checking their passport stamps.